# Python :TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I am using a function to instansiate the python classes .

Hers is the class structure

```
from DB.models import ApiKey,ServiceProvider

class SMSMrg( object ):
    _instance = None
    class Singleton:
        def __init__(self):
            self.username = None
            self.password = None
            self.allsp = []
            self.classnames = {}
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(SMSMrg, cls).__new__(
                                cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def loadsettings(self):

        get_all_sp = ServiceProvider.objects.filter(status = False)
        for (options,obj) in enumerate(get_all_sp):
            cla = str(obj.class_Name)
            self.classnames[cla] = cla
        print self.classnames

        for (options,obj) in enumerate(get_all_sp):
            cla = str(obj.class_Name)
            class_object = self.classnames[cla](obj.userName,obj.password,obj.sendingurl)

       # self.allsp = get_all_sp 
    def send(self):
        print "+++++++++++++++++++== Global send "


if __name__ == "__main__":

    b = SMSMrg()
    b.loadsettings()
```

I have stored the classnames in database and I have defined each class structures on different  files .

Like `cla`  will contain a class name .

But when i am calling above function i am getting the type error .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "allsms.py", line 30, in <module>
    b.loadsettings()
  File "allsms.py", line 21, in loadsettings
    class_object = cla(obj.userName,obj.password,obj.sendingurl)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Please tell me how can instansiate all the classes which names are present in my db .

Comment: What is `obj`? Is it an instance of the class?

Comment: yes it is instance of the model class

Comment: Why are you writing `Singleton` as a class inside a class? Also is `__new__` badly indented or is it really part of `SMSMrg` and not of `Singleton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said `cla` contains the name of the class, which means that you can't use it as a callable.

You can build a `dict` and take the class object from there:

```
from somemodule import SomeClass

class TheClass(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password, url):
        #do stuff

class AnOtherClass(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password, url):
        # do stuff

CLASS_NAMES_TO_CLASSES = {
    # Note: TheClass is *not* a string, is the class!!!
    'FirstName': TheClass,
    'SecondName': AnOtherClass,
    'SomeClass': SomeClass,
    }

class SMSMrg(object):
    #do stuff
    def loadsettings(self):
       get_all_sp = ServiceProvider.objects.filter(status = True)
       for obj in get_all_sp:
           SERVIVEPROVIDER = obj.class_Name
           cla = str(SERVIVEPROVIDER)
           class_object = CLASS_NAMES_TO_CLASSES[cla](obj.userName,obj.password,obj.sendingurl)
```

This method requires you to be able to build such a `dict`, so either you know ahead which classes could end up in the db or you can't use this method.

Note that `CLASS_NAMES_TO_CLASSES` is *not* a dictionary that maps strings to strings. It maps strings to class objects. If you import the class `SomeClass` from a module then you have to put it inside the dictionary.

An other method could be to use `eval` to evaluate the class name, but you should avoid this if the db contains data from users(which is not safe).

An other option that *might* turn out useful is to avoid saving the class names and instead use `pickle` to save the instances directly.

Comment: @masterofdestiny You are *not* doing what I showed here. I'll update my answer to make clearer what I meant.

Comment: MY DICT IS RETURNING {u'MessageNet': u'MessageNet'}

Comment: @masterofdestiny As I said you are doing it wrong. The `dict` should **not** be created from the database. You must create it *before*. Look at my example. The `dict` is created at the module level with all the classes that could come up. If that's not your situation then you *must* provide more information about where the classes are defined etc, otherwise we can't tell you how to solve this.

Comment: as i said "I have stored the classnames in database and I have defined each class structures on different files"  every information like classname are stored in the database only and my intention is whenever i run this script all the classes present in the database must instansiated so that i am creating this application as singleton .

Comment: @masterofdestiny To instantiate the classes you **must** be able to access them in some way. If you can do that, then you can also build a `dict` of names to classes like the one I showed here. You can use `getattr` if you don't want to hardcode the class names. Also you can `pickle` the `dict` obtained in the database and retrieve it for later use. On a side note I think it would have been easier to simply pickle the instance objects into the database, in this way everything is handled for you by `pickle`.

Comment: def loadsettings(self):
        get_all_sp = ServiceProvider.objects.filter(status = False)
        for obj in get_all_sp:
            cla = obj.class_Name
            a=globals()[str(obj.class_Name)](obj.userName,obj.password,obj.sendingurl)
            self.allsp.append(a)

Comment: @masterofdestiny Yes. You got the idea, but I'd rather have a separate `dict` and avoid using `globals`. Otherwise if you put something wrong in the database you wont end up with really strange bugs.

Answer (score 1):

On the line `cla = str(SERVIVEPROVIDER)` you convert `SERVIVEPROVIDER` to string. And on the next line you are trying to call it, thus you get an error...

Answer (score 1):

```
 # Means `cla` is pointing to a string
cla = str(SERVIVEPROVIDER)

# there is no function called `cla` now it contains a string
cla(obj.userName,obj.password,obj.sendingurl)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please tell me how can instansiate all the classes which names are
>   present in my db .

Try this:

```
class A(object): pass
class B(object): pass

class_names = {'first': A, 'second': B}
obj = class_names['first']()
type(obj)
<class 'yourmodule.A'>
```

Or, if your classes are stored somewhere else, say in a module called `mymodule`:

```
import mymodule
obj = getattr(mymodule, 'A')()
```